# Проблема с string.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, строки

В файле string.xml выдается ошибка ""multiple root tags". Из-за чего она может возникнуть и как ее решить?[image: Вот код.]

Comment: "multiple root tags" переводится как "несколько корневых тегов". Что собственно и наблюдается: один корневой тег resources со вложенным string, и три корневых string.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте перенести стринги в головной тэг:

```
<resources>
    <string> </string>

    <string> </string>
    <string> </string>
    <string> </string>
</resources>
```